# MATLAB: Problems with plotting dates on x-axis (line graph)

Tags: matlab, date, datetime, plot

I, again, hope for your help with the following MATLAB problem:

I imported a csv-file from Excel into MATLAB, using the import tool. The data consists of dates (format dd.mm.yy HH:mm) for the x-axis and temperature data for the y-axis. Now, with the import tool I got to choose "datetime" and the format. So far, so good. When I try to plot the data as follows:

```
plot(Feistertal1.Date,Feistertal1.TempC)
```

I get a very weird plot (I attached a screenshot). If I use number (doubles) insted of datetime, I get the same graph I got in excel (and one that makes sense:)). I guess I haveto convert the dates somehow for it to work but I can't seem to find any answers and I just can't figure out how to do it. Can anyone please help?

Thanks very much in advance,

Tamara

[strange looking plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKtgx.png)

[correct plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhqH1.jpg)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what the plot should look like (with the wrong x tick labels)?

Comment: @JustinWager I posted it in the original question above (didn't know how to add a screenshot in a comment).

Comment: Maybe you should sort your date or remove data having the same date.

Comment: I found the mistake :). When choosing the format I need to type in capital letters for the months, yo: dd.MM.yy HH:mm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the mistake you found, you can use the `datetick` function to show the date in proper format on your x-axis ticks.

See: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetick.html

Answer (score 0):

So the mistake was the date format I typed in. The correct format of the date is: dd.MM.yy HH:mm (so the months in capital letters)